# X and Y axis disappears after hovering mouse

Tags: d3.js

I have d3 line graph with zoom and hover tooltip.[Graph looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EeRT.png)

Everything works fine, excep one thing: when I hover mouse on graph, and then drag my mouse out of my plot - X and Y axis disappears. Axis appears again, when mouse is on the plot.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
 bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.created_at; }).left;
 formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");






var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.created_at); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.temp); });

    var line2 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x2(d.created_at); })
        .y(function (d) { return y2(d.temp); });

    var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0);


    var Line_chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");


    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");





var data = jsonfile

data.forEach(function(d){
  d.created_at = parseDate(d.created_at);
  d.temp = +d.temp;
});


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.created_at; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.temp; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());


    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);

    Line_chart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

    context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line2);


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());












    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);








        focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

    // append the y line
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);

    // append the circle at the intersection
    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("r", 4);

    // place the value at the intersection
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y1")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "-.3em");
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y2")
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "-.3em");

    // place the date at the intersection
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y3")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "1em");
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y4")
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "1em");



 function mousemove() {
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
            i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
            d0 = data[i - 1],
            d1 = data[i],
            d = x0 - d0.created_at > d1.created_at - x0 ? d1 : d0;

        focus.select("circle.y")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")");

        focus.select("text.y1")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
            .text(d.temp);

        focus.select("text.y2")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
            .text(d.temp);

        focus.select("text.y3")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
            .text(formatDate(d.created_at));

        focus.select("text.y4")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
            .text(formatDate(d.created_at));

        focus.select(".x")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + x(d.created_at) + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
                       .attr("y2", height - y(d.temp));

        focus.select(".y")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + width * -1 + "," +
                                 y(d.temp) + ")")
                       .attr("x2", width + width);
    }





  console.log(data);

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  Line_chart.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  Line_chart.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}
});
```

It's not necessary to figured out exactly this problem, any ideas, about what can cause this will be appreciated.

Comment: Without .on(mouseout) axis do not disappears and everything is fine, very weird thing =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. I believe the problem is because you are using

```
.on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
.on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
```

What this is doing is that everything which is assigned to the focus variable (which in your case includes the axis) is being set to `display: none` when you mouse out, and everything is being set to null which when you mouse over. This is not weird but just misunderstood.

Unfortunately it is not clear what you would like the graph to do, i.e. what you would like to appear / disappear on mouse movements from your question. Also you should provide some dummy/sample data for the user to reproduce your issue.

If you update the question with more details on what you would like  and some sample data I can take another look at this for you. Just leave a comment below once you have updated the information.

**Update**

Based on the comments below: if you would like to separate the axis from the focus simply assign it to a different variable. For example:

1. Declare a variable and append a separate group for the axis:

   ```
   var axisg = svg.append("g") //appends a new group for the axis
      .attr("class", "axisg") //assign it a class
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // move it appropriately with the margins.
   ```
2. Next instead of appending the axis components within the focus variable assign them to the axisg variable:

   ```
    //append the x and y axis components 
     axisg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);

    axisg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
     .call(yAxis);
   ```

Comment: I've deleted mouseout line and pushed to project ( no time for rewriting). It will be great for me to understand how to separate focus and axis. Graph is just a line chart with zooming and tooltip on hover.

Comment: Hi Damien, I have updated the answer with more information on how you can assign the axis to a separate variable. Also please mark this question as answered as I have answered your query above, and remember to upvote it if you feel it is a good answer. Feel free to comment if you have more doubts and I would be happy to clarify. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers